# Javascript - Project Euler Solution 8, code not working properly

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginning programmer, and am trying to solve [Project Euler Problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) (finding the thirteen adjacent digits with the greatest product). Here is my code:

```
var n = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

function multiplyNext13(a){
    var result = 1;
    for (i = a; i < a + 13; i++){
        result *= Number(n[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

function getAnswer(){
    var answer = 5000940;
    for (i = 0; i < 988; i++){
        if (multiplyNext13(i) > answer){
            answer = multiplyNext13(i);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

The function `getAnswer()` keeps giving me `answer = 0`, but I don't know what's wrong. I tested the function `multiplyNext13()` and I believe it's working properly.

What's wrong with this code? Why isn't it working?

Comment: Please mention what the question of problem 8 is, and what the result should be.

Comment: @Juhana That would be cool but I don't think the point of SO is really to solve the problem, but rather to fix specific issues.

Comment: `n[i]` is not what you think.

Comment: That was mostly for the benefit of future questions; this one happened to have an obvious syntactical answer but if the problem were in the program's logic there would be no way to answer without knowing what the goal is.

Comment: @dystroy: How do you identify specific issues if you don't know what the code is actually trying to do?

Comment: @mins - What do _you_ think `n[i]` is and how do you think that affects the behavior of OP's code? (Hint: The code would work the same if `Number(n[i])` were replaced by `n[i]`.)

Comment: I think the OP wants to get the character in the string at index `i`, what is obtained is `0` or `null` as `n` is not an array.

Comment: @mins - Wrong (at least as of EcmaScript 5). `n[i]` will return the substring consisting of the `i`-th character of `n`. Try it out, or check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access).

Comment: @TedHopp: fair enough, stand corrected.

Comment: The question is : 

The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

Comment: Or simply go to this link:

https://projecteuler.net/problem=8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have only one variable `i` in your whole program, because you failed to declare it with `var`.

This means each time you enter the loop in `multiplyNext13` you also advance the loop in `getAnswer`.

This also means the value you set in `answer = multiplyNext13(i);` isn't the same that the one you just computed in `if (multiplyNext13(i) > answer){` (note that this double computation also makes your code slower).

Change

```
for (i = a; i < a + 13; i++){
```

to

```
for (var i = a; i < a + 13; i++){
```

(and of course the same for the other loop).

Once I fix that, I get this result : `23514624000`

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/sapaxudovi/1/edit)